# Transformation of Julia set sequence emerging from meromorphic function

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, meromorphic-functions, julia-set

I consider a sequence of meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere $f_k:\hat{\mathbb{C}} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ of the form

$$f_k(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}\dfrac{1}{(z-p_j)^{c_j}}$$
with poles $p_j$ of order $c_j$. Additionally, I assume $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and the sequence has a given recurrence relation $f_{k+1}=\mathcal{T}(f_k)$ (non-linear in general but of order $1$ for the time being).

From any $f_k$ one can obtain a Julia set $\mathcal{J}_k$ (see for example here https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9310226). I was wondering how the recurrence relation translates to the setting of the Julia sets as shown in the diagram by $\nu$.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
f_k @>\mathcal{T}>> f_{k+1}\\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
\mathcal{J}_k @>>\nu> \mathcal{J}_{k+1}
\end{CD}

Having done some more research online, I found the publication https://www.jstor.org/stable/2162327, which "reduces" the problem to analyzing the push-forward measure $\mathcal{T}^{\ast}\mu(f_k)$ of $\mu(f_k)$, the measure of maximal entropy supported on $\mathcal{J}_k$, and iterates of $f_k$, $f_{k+1}$ and potentially some other rational function $g$.
Basically, one would need to define $g$ in such a way that $\mu(g)=\mathcal{T}^{\ast}\mu(f_k)=\mu(\mathcal{T}(f_k))$. The attentive reader will notice that $\mathcal{T}^{\ast}\mu(f_k)$ is somewhat undefined and I have no idea how to define it properly. Does anyone have an idea how the push-forward of maximale entropy measures could be defined?
If I have this, then a new diagram could look like this.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
f_k @>\mathcal{T}>> f_{k+1}\\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
\mu(f_k) @>>\mathcal{T}^{\ast}> \mu(f_{k+1})\\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
\mathcal{J}_k @>>\nu> \mathcal{J}_{k+1}
\end{CD}

Now we can think about the map $\nu$ differently, but it should obviously still be defined as $\mu:\Omega\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ is the power set of $\mathbb{C}$ and, no longer intuitively, it depends on $k$ if and only if $\mathcal{T}$ depends on $k$.

I am interested in how the properties of $\mathcal{T}$ translate to $\nu$ and whether there is a name for these maps.

Comment: `\backslash` is not the same as `\setminus`. I corrected this in this question.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the ```\setminus```